# Is this a bug of ConstraintLayout? Why is the textview not visible at all?

Tags: android

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/comment_search_border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint=" Search"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
        android:paddingVertical="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/write_comment"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/write_comment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/search"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/search"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/search">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="123" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want:

- the edittext and the textview to be in the same row:

```
____________________  ___________
|     edittext      | | textview |
--------------------  -----------
```

- the textview to have the same height as the edittext,
- and the outer ConstraintLayout's height to be determined by the edittext's height,
- and the edittext to take all of the parent's width except the necessary width of the textview.

Comment: It doesn't work because first view takes whole height. Instead of constraining first element's bottom to parent's bottom - you should constraint it's bottom to second element's top. Anyway, you should read how constraining works - https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout

Comment: `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0"`?????

Comment: @deadfish I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough before... But I want the edittext and the textview to be in one row, what you are saying seems to only get them in one column?

Comment: @C.F.G removing this line doesn't solve the problem either, nothing happened.

Comment: @TanTelephone: Is this a joke? or puzzle? Look at `android:visibility="gone"
`

Answer (score 0):

Set weight of first view "2" and second view (LinearLayout) "1" ( not 0). Also make first view visible. (`android:visibility="visible"` not `gone`)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
        android:background="@drawable/comment_search_border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint=" Search"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
        android:paddingVertical="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/write_comment"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/write_comment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/search"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/search"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/search">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="123" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```